# Mac backup / sync software

Tags: osx, backup, file-synchronization, version-control

I'm looking for a mac program that would allow me to work following way:

1. Keep all my files on Windows/Samba Share (on Synology NAS device that can also act as rsync server).
2. When I need to work on some files, I'd like the software to have a browser that would allow me to find those files on the Share and mark them.
3. The software would copy those files to my local disk to special folder (while preserving directory structure).
4. The software would keep the copy on the share in sync with the one on my local disk.
5. If I delete file from local disk, the software would stop syncing it to the Share.
6. The software should keep and display a log of what happens to the files on local disk, when they are changed, when they are synced back, when they are deleted.

Bonus points for being open source and cross platform.

Answer (score 1):

[git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/) allows storage to both cloud and local devices, synchronization between them and archiving of files off of your local machine.

- Free & Open Source, written in [Haskell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_(programming_language))
- Mac OS-X, Linux and Windows *currently in beta*
- Preserves directory structure including changes due to renames/moves.
- Specifically allows archiving - see the [walk through](https://git-annex.branchable.com/assistant/archival_walkthrough/)
- Supports various & [multiple](https://git-annex.branchable.com/special_remotes/) cloud archive services and you can [add your own](https://git-annex.branchable.com/special_remotes/external/) *without necessarily having to learn Haskell*.